# Mongo Query in Update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to Mongo (an SQL guy by preference) and working in an application set up by someone else. I have records like this, plus more information:

```
City:
    name: "name"
    State: ObjectId({id here})
    slug: "slug"
    images: [images]
    ...
```

And state also has a text field with slug in it. I want to create a new entry for a city for related Cities. So it would be an array with the images, the slug, the state slug, and the name. I have tried the following, but I end up with query information for the stateSlug:

```
db.getCollection('city').find(
{
    $or: 
        [
            {"name": "Camden"}, 
            {"name": "Virginia Beach"}, 
            {"name": "Annapolis"}
        ]
},{images:1, slug:1, state:1, name:1}
).forEach(function(city){
    db.city.update({"name" : "Lewes"}, {$push:{'relatedCities':
        { "images":city.images,
          "slug":city.slug,
          "name":city.name,
          "stateSlug":db.state.find(city.state,{slug:1,_id:0})
        }
    }})
})
```

Is there a way that I can make this query work? I have the names that are used for the queries in an excel file and a python script that can output the info in this format to a js file to execute if I can figure out how to make it work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you need to take involves running an aggregation pipeline that uses the following pipeline steps (in the order given):

1) **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** to filter documents that get into the pipeline. Consider using an **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator instead of **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** if your expression involves [equality checks for the value of the same field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in). This is similar to the SQL's `WHERE` clause where e.g.

```
SELECT name, images, state, slug
WHERE name in ('Camden', 'Virginia Beach', 'Annapolis')
```

instead of

```
SELECT name, images, state, slug
WHERE 
    (name = 'Camden') OR
    (name = 'Virginia Beach') OR
    (name = 'Annapolis')
```

2) **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** to do a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection which is the `state` collection for processing. The **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** stage does an equality match between the `state` field from the input documents with the `_id` field from the documents of the "joined" collection state.

3) **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** - The new field from the results of the previous **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline is an array so you'll need to add an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** stage to your pipeline so that you can flatten the array as it needs to be processed further down as a denormalised field.

4) **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to group all the documents and create an array relatedCities that has fields from the previous pipeline. The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. You can read more about the aggregation functions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator).

The accumulator operator you would need to create the array is **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**.

5) **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** final stage is then used to select or rename properties from the documents in the preceding pipeline - similar to what you would do with the SQL `SELECT` clause. For creating a new field with a string literal, you would need the **[`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal)** operator which is similar to SQL's `AS` or `ALIAS` keyword.

---

One thing to note here is when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So Mongo executes the above pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $match | $lookup | $unwind | $group | $project => result
```

Now, when you run this aggregation pipeline in mongo shell, the results will be an array which you get when you use the **[`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)** method on the **[`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor)** returned from calling the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method on the `city` collection.

You can then create the new city entry in the `city` collection by first accessing the only element in the result array through the zero index which is the new `city` document that has the aggregated fields, and use the **[`save()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/)** method on the city collection to persist the document.

The following example demonstrates the above concept:

```
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "name": { "$in": ["Camden", "Virginia Beach", "Annapolis"] }
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "state",
                "localField": "state",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "states"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$states" },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "relatedCities": {
                    "$push": {
                        "images": "$images",
                        "slug": "$slug",
                        "name": "$name",
                        "stateSlug": "$states.slug"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "name": { "$literal": "Lewes" },
                "relatedCities": 1
            }
        }       
    ],
    newCity = db.city.aggregate(pipeline).toArray()[0];

db.city.save(newCity);
```